# How to sum varying groups of numbers in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a group of numbers:

```
A1   12
A2   13
A3   3
A4   5
A5
A6   1
A7   8
A8   9
A9
A10  2
A11  19
A12
and so on...
```

I would like cell B5 to show 33 (sum of A1 to A4), B9 to show 18 (sum of A6 to A8), A12 to show 21 (sum of A10 to A11), etc.  Basically, the number of values to be added is random and depends on whether the cell is blank -- so if A5 is blank, B5 will have a value.

Comment: Look up SumIf in the excel help. That may help.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: The trick about this question is that the ranges keep changing, so there has to be a way of tracking that.  I propose helper columns.  Is there another way of doing that within the `SumIf`?

Answer (score 4):

Use this formula in cell B2 and copy down as far as your data in column A.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),SUM($A$1:A1)-SUM($B$1:B1),"")
```

[image]

In words: Sum everything in column A above the current row and subtract the sum of everything in column B above the current row. Do this only for rows where A is blank.

Comment: thank you! this is what I'm looking for. this solved my problem.

Comment: @user338420, if this solved your question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few helper columns and some neat formulas to get what you want with the following assumptions:

- There will not be multiple blank lines in a row (like both A3 and A4 are blank).
- The first line will not be blank.
- You don't care about the extra column use & can hide them.

What we are doing is figuring out how many rows there are between blanks, and then creating a range out of that.  We then plug that range into the SUM formula only for blank rows.

**Range counter:**  Use column C and enter a `1` in the first row.  Then starting from row 2, enter the formula `=IF(C1="", 1, IF(A2="","",C1+1))`.  If a row is blank, it will start at 1.  Otherwise, it will keep incrementing the counter.

**Create range text:**  Using column D, starting in row 2, enter the formula `=IF(C2="", CONCATENATE("A",ROW()-C1,":A",ROW()-1),"")`.  This will create text that looks like `A1:A3`.

**Plug into SUM formula:**  Use column B and starting from row 2, enter the formula `=IF(A2="",SUM(INDIRECT(D2)),"")`.  Only if the row is blank, it will perform the `SUM`.

Drag the rows down to see the magic!

Here are some screen shots of it in action & showing the formulas:

[image: In action]

[image: With formulas]

Answer (score -1):

You should learn how to use *functions* in Excel to make your life easier. There is a function called **SUM** function and what it does is to add the number in two or more cells. To get the sum of the first four entries in Column A, type

> =SUM(A1:A4)

This function would add the numbers from A1 to A4. You can input this function on the empty field above the column names that says fx. I could not post a picture yet. If you want B5 to contain this value, you should click on the cell B5 and input the SUM function that I have provided in the **fx** field.

As for the others, you could go to b9 and b12 and input the following functions:

> =SUM(A6,A7,A8)

and

```
>=SUM(A10,A11)
```

Comment: no, but the problem is the number of values is not fix, first group may contain 3 digits only.
i'm thinking of using indirect function to determine where the values will end then use row & column function to determine where shall the range start.
i'm also thinking to use IF function, if A is empty, then B will sum up A.